# Change text of TextView, then use layout programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select an option" />
```

I use the above layout to set the default text of a spinner button, using this class:

```
/**
 * Decorator Adapter to allow a Spinner to show a 'Nothing Selected...' initially
 * displayed instead of the first choice in the Adapter.
 */
public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter, ListAdapter {

    protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
    protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
    protected Context context;
    protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
    protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    /**
     * Use this constructor to have NO 'Select One...' item, instead use
     * the standard prompt or nothing at all.
     * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter.
     * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps
     * you want text grayed out like a prompt...
     * @param context
     */
    public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
      SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
      int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {

        this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
    }

    /**
     * Use this constructor to Define your 'Select One...' layout as the first
     * row in the returned choices.
     * If you do this, you probably don't want a prompt on your spinner or it'll
     * have two 'Select' rows.
     * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter. Should probably return false for isEnabled(0)
     * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps you want
     * text grayed out like a prompt...
     * @param nothingSelectedDropdownLayout layout for your 'Select an Item...' in
     * the dropdown.
     * @param context
     */
    public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
            int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, Context context) {
        this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
        this.context = context;
        this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
        this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // This provides the View for the Selected Item in the Spinner, not
        // the dropdown (unless dropdownView is not set).
        if (position == 0) {
            return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
        }
        return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use
                                                 // the convertView if possible.
    }

    /**
     * View to show in Spinner with Nothing Selected
     * Override this to do something dynamic... e.g. "37 Options Found"
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Android BUG! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 -
        // Spinner does not support multiple view types
        if (position == 0) {
            return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ?
              new View(context) :
              getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
        }

        // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
        return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
    }

    /**
     * Override this to do something dynamic... For example, "Pick your favorite
     * of these 37".
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = adapter.getCount();
        return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position >= EXTRA ? adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA) : position - EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return adapter.hasStableIds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return adapter.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position != 0; // Don't allow the 'nothing selected'
                                             // item to be picked.
    }

}
```

I initialize the above class like this:

```
NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter myAdapter = new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(spinnerAdapter, R.layout.layout_pasted_above, getContext());
myAdapter.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

However, I want to be able to change the text of the above layout programmatically.

How would I achieve this?

-

*Apparently StackOverflow needs more words for me to submit this post, but I have no other important details to add, so I'm just adding this text in so I can actually submit this.*

Comment: Does the `TextView` belongs to this layout `R.layout.layout_pasted_above` ?

Comment: @Greggz Yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of your widget and set it to a textview variable in your java class

```
TextView variable= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
```

then set the text to whatever string you want

```
variable.setText("insert your text");
```

Comment: That's not going to work, because of the way the layout is referenced here: `NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter myAdapter = new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(spinnerAdapter, R.layout.layout_pasted_above, getContext());`. I believe I will need to inflate the layout, change the text, and then somehow reference the inflated layout in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the reference of TextView here after inflating the method.

```
 protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View nothingSelectedView  = layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, 
    parent, false);
    TextView labelText =(TextView)nothingSelectedView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    labelText.setText("Set You Text Here"); 
    return nothingSelectedView;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help, as I want to be able to make it as flexible as possible. Setting the text in that method means I can't have different text for a different spinner.

Comment: Its same textView.. we are not adding new text view,Instead getting reference of TextView.

Comment: Yes, but I have multiple spinners and I want them all to have different text. Doing it in your method means all my spinners will have the same text.

Comment: In the question you did not mentioned that.. You might need to keep some data structure to keep track of selected item.  if(selected){//set desired value }else default value

Answer (score 0):

Just create a field, and expose a public method.

```
protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View nothingSelectedView = layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, 
                                                        parent, 
                                                        false);

    textViewField = (TextView) nothingSelectedView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    return nothingSelectedView;
}

// Expose public method
public void changeText(String text) {
    textViewField.setText(text);
}
```

Call it from wherever

```
adapter.changeText("new text");
```

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` on the line `textViewField.setText(text);`

Comment: Your textViewField is null. Are you using the right id ? I used `R.id.label` as a placeholder. Use your real one..

Comment: Yes, I've double checked

Comment: Hum.. try `textViewField = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.label)`

Comment: Odd, same thing again

Comment: Show me the layout xml pls

Comment: It is in my original question above.